# How to make image stay inside the div box on scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the image position fixed inside div and code is gven below

```
#content{
margin-top:100px; 
width:900px; 
color:#009;
border:1px solid red;
overflow:hidden;
display:block;

}
img {
float:left; 
position:fixed;
top:140px;
padding:50px;
}
#text{
 display:block;
border:1px solid green; 
width:500px; 
height:1200px;
float:right; 
overflow:scroll;
}
#footer{
 clear:both;
 width:600px;
 height:300px;
 border:2x solid blue;
 color:#939; 
}
```

HTML is

```
<div id="content" >
<img src="bar.jpg" width="46" height="639" /> 
<div id="text">
ggggggggggggggggggfgdfgdfgdgdfgdgdfgdf
</div>
</div>


<div id="footer">

Footer text
</div>
</body>
```

Now when i scroll down then image comes out of the content div box.
IS there any way so that even if i scroll the image bar should stay inside the div box.

The screen shot shows my problem
First Screen is ok without scrolling

[alt text http://img293.imageshack.us/img293/8640/bar1k.png](http://img293.imageshack.us/img293/8640/bar1k.png)

But when i scroll the text full then it covers my footer as well

[alt text http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/4393/bar2z.png](http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/4393/bar2z.png)

```
 I want that image should scroll with the scroll bar but it should not come outside the div box . Is that possible. Basically the div box should be the boundary of the image. THe image should not come out of the div box any time but it should scroll in between that with the length of div box
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you want that blue bar to stay within the red box, right?

if that's the case you need to have the css for the blue box as

```
img {
 position: absolute;
 top:140px;
 left:50px;
}
```

and also the container has to have

```
#content{
 ...
 position: relative;
}
```

`position: relative` will make the blue bar absolutely positioned with respect to `#content` rather than the `document` object.

Answer (score 0):

> position: fixed
>
> Generates an absolutely positioned
>   element, positioned relative to the
>   browser window. The element's position
>   is specified with the "left", "top",
>   "right", and "bottom" properties

In other words you can't "fix" your image inside of div only relative to browser window.

---

Follow-up:

If you want that image to always be  on the same place in the background do it with CSS:

```
body {background: transparent url(bar.jpg) bottom left no-repeat; 
      background-attachment:fixed}
```

Answer (score 0):

`position: fixed` positions your image relative to **browser window**

If you want to position it relative to the parent `div`, you should use `position: absolute`

Comment: but if i use absolute , then image does not scroll when i scroll down the browser window

Comment: This seems to be contradictory to what you said in the original question.

Do you want the image to move when scrolling? Or not?

Comment: I want that image should scroll  with the scroll bar but it should not come outside the div box . Is that possible. Basically the div box should be the boundary of the image. THe image should not come out of the div box any time but it should scroll in between that with the length of div box

Comment: Ooo, that I'm not sure is possible.

Answer (score 0):

from what i see, just remove the position: fixed from your img tag styles

```
img {
    float:left;
    padding:50px;
}
```

I dont know if is just because you made a quick demo to show us, but never apply a style to a tag, its better to use ID's or Classes

if you want to keep a margin of 140 pixels from the top of the div containing the image, use:

```
img {
    margin-top: 140px;
}
```

Comment: @GerManson, I'm going to vehemently disagree on your assertion that you should never style a tag. I think it's completely reasonable and highly preferable to style a tag if you need to it to work on all instances of that tag.

Comment: yes, I agree with you, but I've seen people applying styles to tags when they dont really want the style applied to the whole site.